# How to disable and enable oculus teleportation (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Ok my problem is the oculus touchpads use the same grip controls to determine teleportation/aiming and picking up objects. I don't want to change the controls because they're intuitive, but I cant have the teleportation randomly coming up as it does now when they are picking up an object.

There is no disable function in the Oculus standard Locomotion Teleport class, and Ive tried disabling it like this:

```
private void Update()
    {

        locomotionTeleport = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<LocomotionTeleport>();
        // print(GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<OVRGrabber>()[0].isGrabbing || GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<OVRGrabber>()[1].isGrabbing);
        locomotionTeleport.enabled = !(GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<OVRGrabber>()[0].isGrabbing || GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<OVRGrabber>()[1].isGrabbing);
    }
```

Where I track if object is being grabbed in the OVRGrabbers:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otherCollider)
    {
        // Get the grab trigger
        OVRGrabbable grabbable = otherCollider.GetComponent<OVRGrabbable>() ?? otherCollider.GetComponentInParent<OVRGrabbable>();
        if (grabbable == null) return;

        if(grabbable != null)
        {
            isGrabbing = true;

        }
```

But this does nothing. Nothing I try setting bool flags in the teleportation class does anything. How can I prevent teleportation if an object is being picked up, and reenable afterwards?